# Reputation changes with more than 3 digits overflowing container

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, user-interface, top-bar

Reputation changes that are larger than 99 are shown out of the container it must be in.

See these pictures for `+100`:

[image]

And this for `+1000`:

[image]

Tested with `Safari 9` and `Chrome 47` on `OS X El Capitan`.

Comment: Do you get reputation changes over 999 often?

Comment: @Oded No, but I don't believe that's the point.

Comment: So, something that has zero to no impact on a tiny number of users should be fixed?

Comment: @Oded I'm not saying it is preventing users from using SE, it's just a little thing I noticed when I joined a new community and gained `+100` rep. I think all details matter. It's not about functionality.

Answer (score 9):

This is an incredibly rare occurrence. And it has a **tiny** impact on the UI and nothing else.

As soon as the user clicks on the the notification, it goes away.

I see no point in fixing this.

Comment: Penance for being brilliant, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Oded's answer, I would like to point out that the extension/overlap is only happening on the right side, so it is not overlapping with the comments notification icon.

So, it doesn't really matter a lot as it is a very rare occurrence.  (I doubt even Jon Skeet experiences it or not!)

Anyways, if I were the user, I would love the fact that my rep count is overflowing the container.

Comment: All Jon Skeet needs to do to get a +10000 there is wait 50 days without clicking it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard  Ha ha.  I assumed no waiting though :D

(Who'll wait more than one day for checking rep, anyways, especially when you've got a stellar streak going on!)

Comment: Without the rep cap you're right, couple of days and he gets +10000, however there's the 200 rep cap holding him back. ;-)

Comment: Actually Jon Skeet will experience it most days, at least on the days when he goes to bed/stops looking at SE before midnight, because he is in the UTC time zone. By the time he will get up he will already have hit the rep cap, so that is +200.

Comment: @wythagoras I'm talking about a +1k rep notification

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see what there is to "fix" in the first place.

When the content of the notification grows longer than the default width will accommodate, either the notification must stretch to fit the content, or the content itself must shrink.  Shrinking the text would hurt readability, whereas there's plenty of space in the top bar for the notification to expand.  Thus, it seems to me that the notification is behaving exactly as it should.